# Loop through an object and get the value from all its variables

Tags: java, loops, object

I'm using Gson to parse an array of JSON objects to POJO. I am then using a `for-loop` to send each one of the parsed objects to a method for processing. I cannot seem to find a way to loop through the individual objects and get the values contained within.

For instance:

```
private Double thing1;
private Double thing2;
private Dboule thing3;

private void doSomething(MyObject myObj){
 ...myObject contains thing1, thing2, thing3 which are each doubles.

//I want to loop through the entire object, 
//grab thing1's value and do something with it, then grab thing2's value... etc. 

 
}
```

Is this easily done? I have been trying for a while now and I cannot seem to get it to work. I can grab them individually easily enough by using:

```
myObj.thing1
```

But it will need to be done in a loop as there are a TON of values coming in.

UPDATE: This ALMOST works but it prints the entire object and then it prints the individual object values.  How can i get it to just print the individual values without first printing everything?

```
for(Field field : data.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
    Object value = field.get(data);
    System.out.println(value);        
}
```

Output:

```
    [{"accel_1":0.012,"accel_2":0.125,"accel_3":0.03,"accel_4":0.012,"accel_5":0.125,"accel_6":0.03,"accel_7":0.012,"accel_8":0.125,"accel_9":0.03,"accel_10":0.012,"accel_11":0.125,"accel_12":0.03},{"accel_1":0.18,"accel_2":0.26,"accel_3":0.05,"accel_4":0.18,"accel_5":0.26,"accel_6":0.05,"accel_7":0.18,"accel_8":0.26,"accel_9":0.05,"accel_10":0.18,"accel_11":0.26,"accel_12":0.05},{"accel_1":0.06,"accel_2":0.02,"accel_3":0.03,"accel_4":0.06,"accel_5":0.02,"accel_6":0.03,"accel_7":0.06,"accel_8":0.02,"accel_9":0.03,"accel_10":0.06,"accel_11":0.02,"accel_12":0.03}]
0.012
0.125
0.03
0.012
0.125
0.03
0.012
0.125
0.03
0.012
0.125
0.03
[{"accel_1":0.012,"accel_2":0.125,"accel_3":0.03,"accel_4":0.012,"accel_5":0.125,"accel_6":0.03,"accel_7":0.012,"accel_8":0.125,"accel_9":0.03,"accel_10":0.012,"accel_11":0.125,"accel_12":0.03},{"accel_1":0.18,"accel_2":0.26,"accel_3":0.05,"accel_4":0.18,"accel_5":0.26,"accel_6":0.05,"accel_7":0.18,"accel_8":0.26,"accel_9":0.05,"accel_10":0.18,"accel_11":0.26,"accel_12":0.05},{"accel_1":0.06,"accel_2":0.02,"accel_3":0.03,"accel_4":0.06,"accel_5":0.02,"accel_6":0.03,"accel_7":0.06,"accel_8":0.02,"accel_9":0.03,"accel_10":0.06,"accel_11":0.02,"accel_12":0.03}]
0.18
0.26
0.05
0.18
0.26
0.05
0.18
0.26
0.05
0.18
0.26
0.05
[{"accel_1":0.012,"accel_2":0.125,"accel_3":0.03,"accel_4":0.012,"accel_5":0.125,"accel_6":0.03,"accel_7":0.012,"accel_8":0.125,"accel_9":0.03,"accel_10":0.012,"accel_11":0.125,"accel_12":0.03},{"accel_1":0.18,"accel_2":0.26,"accel_3":0.05,"accel_4":0.18,"accel_5":0.26,"accel_6":0.05,"accel_7":0.18,"accel_8":0.26,"accel_9":0.05,"accel_10":0.18,"accel_11":0.26,"accel_12":0.05},{"accel_1":0.06,"accel_2":0.02,"accel_3":0.03,"accel_4":0.06,"accel_5":0.02,"accel_6":0.03,"accel_7":0.06,"accel_8":0.02,"accel_9":0.03,"accel_10":0.06,"accel_11":0.02,"accel_12":0.03}]
0.06
0.02
0.03
0.06
0.02
0.03
0.06
0.02
0.03
0.06
0.02
0.03
```

Here are the Full Methods:

```
private void convertJSON(String jsonString) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type data = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyObject>>(){}.getType();
    List<MyObject> fhd = gson.fromJson(jsonString, data);
    for(MyObject current : fhd){
        printIt(current);
    }
}

public void printIt(MyObject data) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    for(Field field : data.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
        Object value = field.get(data);
        System.out.println(value);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use reflection to do this:

```
Field[] fields = games.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

for(Field field: fields) {
    //do stuff
}
```

`getDeclaredFields()`:

> Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, but excludes inherited fields.

Comment: this almost does it. I updated my post. It's NEARLY there.

Comment: @MarcusHolden What are you passing to the `get()` method? (What is `data`?)

Comment: Its an object taken from an array of objects. Here is the mock method:   public void printIt(MyObject data){
    for(Field field : data.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
        Object value = field.get(data);
        System.out.println(value);       
    }
}

Comment: @MarcusHolden Hmm I cannot reproduce this. When I run this code it simply prints out the fields.

Comment: That's whacky. I have uploaded the full methods.

Comment: @MarcusHolden Yes this is strange. I cannot get it to reproduce this. I guess the only thing I can suggest is stepping through it with your debugger to see on what line it's printing the object on

Comment: Strange indeed. I really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: Why dont you print the name of the field too in the println statement to debug where the full object is getting printed. Like: System.out.println(field.getName() + ": " + value);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to loop through the values of an object. If this is the case, then write your method like the following:

```
private void doSomething(MyObject myObj)
{
    Double sum_of_values = 0;
    for (MyObject val : myObj) // "val" will be each Double value within the object.
    { 
        //I don't know what you want to do with the values of your object,
        //but below is an example of getting the sum of values within your object:
        sum_of_values += val; 
        //here I assumed that are values are Double, which in many cases they can be of any type.
        //Or you can send each value to another method and do your stuff there:
        someMethod(val);
        //Or maybe do something else.
    }
}
private void someMethod(Double val)
{
    //do things here.
{
```

I hope this gives you an idea